# How to make my overloaded fraction >> operator recognize negative numbers.

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Okay, so I've been trying to get this to work for the past 2 days now, but to no avail. essentially there is a text file, from which the program extracts fractions and mixed numbers, and my >> operator is supposed to convert them to normal fractions to be outputted by my << operator, which works fine. but as soon as my function hits -8 in the file, the program crashes and ends, leaving me with the "press any key to continue" end prompt on the console. it handles -4/5 and -10/5 no problem, returning -4/5 and -2 respectively. but when the negative number is whole, it crashes.

```
istream& operator>>(istream& input, fraction& fr)
  {
    int Num=0;
    int Den=0;
    int Whole=0;
    input >> Num;
    if (input.peek() == '+')
    {
        Whole = Num;
        input.ignore() >> Num;
        input >> Den;
    }
    else if (input.peek() == '/')
    {
        input.ignore() >> Den;
    }
    else if (input.peek() == ' ')
    {
       input.ignore();
       Den = 1;
    }
    Num = (Whole*Den) + Num;
    fr = fraction(Num, Den);
    return input;
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a default of `Den = 1` instead of 0. It's crashing due to divide by 0.

Comment: woops. that explains why my progress had gone backwards.I must have changed my Den initialization for some reason. I also had a bug for mixed numbers, but while I was writing this comment I realized I was missing a input.ignore() thank you muchly.